# How can we convert a string to a working variable which fetch values in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, variables

I have a case where I need to store a location of each key value of json, so that for each key, it automatically fetches the location and gives the value for it from json.

Here, I have a location of the key 'vehicle_id' inside json 'car' assigned to a variable like:

> String location="jresp.getJSONArray('cars').getJSONObject(0).getString('vehicle_id')"

How do I make it as a variable in JAVA such that this location fetches the value of vehicle_id for me from JSON? I need it like:

> String value=jresp.getJSONArray('cars').getJSONObject(0).getString('vehicle_id');

so that it gives me a value. I've searched in net, but couldn't find it anywhere. Please help me!

Comment: Can't understand , String varibale = jresp.getJSONArray('cars').getJSONObject(0).getString('vehicle_id');  

What u want ??

Comment: I'm sorry that I was not clear. I've updated my question. @Chanky

Comment: I guess you want to use this String variable at some other place like method or other class?  What is exactly the case?

Comment: You want at runtime to compile and interpret arbitrary code as part of a method?  Convoluted and risky.

Comment: @DhaRmvEErsiNgh I've updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: @Taylor Yeah its extremely complex, i just need to know if there is any way to make that string variable work, so it will be useful for my project

Comment: You'll need to look into some runtime expression library like mvel.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the complete statement as a variable like -

```
String location="jresp.getJSONArray('cars').getJSONObject(0).getString('vehicle_id')"
```

You could have 3 different variables like -

```
String jsonArray = "cars";//You might need to do some string processing to get these
int objSeq = 0;
String key = "vehicle_id";
```

Then you can definitely use it in your Java statement -

```
String value=jresp.getJSONArray(jsonArray).getJSONObject(objSeq).getString(key);
```

Comment: Thats a great suggestion. But the problem with this is, we do not know whether the key is present inside a json array of a json object, or it is just inside a json object

Comment: If you are bound to get `"jresp.getJSONArray('cars').getJSONObject(0).getString('vehicle_id')"` such statements, you can have conditional value extraction. In case where `location.indexOf("getJSONArray") < 0`, you will have only 1 variable i.e - the `key`. Its not an array and the value would be a different statement accepting only a single key as `String value = jsonObj.get(key);`

Comment: @RajeevRajan Thanks alot! That helps me to find a proper way to satisfy all conditions! It really helps!